# ColdFusion cfpdf Thumbnail numbering is incorrect

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, thumbnails, cfpdf

I am using the cfpdf function in ColdFusion to create a document packet, i.e. merging a range of documents into one PDF file. The merge works correctly and the thumbnail images correctly link to their respective pages. However, the page numbers shown underneath the thumbnail images are incorrect. At some point in the process, the numbering is restarted as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

This issue only occurs when the `cfpdf` function is given a directory to work with, not when the files are specified individually. Due to the potentially large number of files which may be processed, specifying the files individually would be impractical.

I am using ColdFusion 11.

Has anyone else here experienced this issue or has any remedial suggestions?

The code I am using is:

```
<cfpdf action="merge" 
    directory="C:\temp" <!--- Directory contains multiple PDF files --->
    destination="Packet.pdf"
    order="name" 
    ascending="yes"
    overwrite="yes"
    keepbookmark="yes">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what `C:\temp` contains? Are these PDF files named according to their page number?

Comment: Good point Alex. It contains multiple pdf (*.pdf) files. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing what the `directory` attribute in `<cfpdf>` is supposed to do:

```
<cfdirectory
     action="list" directory="C:\temp\"
     type="file" filter="*.pdf" sort="ASC"
     name="filesToMerge"
>

<cfpdf
    action="merge" destination="Packet.pdf"
    overwrite="yes"
    keepbookmark="yes"
>
    <cfloop query="filesToMerge">
        <cfpdfparam source="#filesToMerge.directory#\#filesToMerge.name#"> 
    </cfloop>
</cfpdf>
```

Does the order in `filesToMerge` return what you expect?

Now try removing all meta data in case the PDF files had their page number stored:

```
<cfpdf
    action="optimize" source="Packet.pdf" destination="Packet_noMeta.pdf"
    algo="bilinear" nometadata="true"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Alex. Unfortunately, it gave me the same results.

Comment: A colleague here mentioned DDX as a possible solution. Does that ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: @KenHaynes Does `filesToMerge` list `61.pdf`, `62.pdf` etc. before `1.pdf`? Are they part of a subfolder? Can you show us a screenshot of the dump?

Comment: That is the odd thing, all the files appear in their correct positions within the merged PDF and all of the thumbnails appear in their correct order. The only problem is that the page numbers displayed under each thumbnail are restarted (at what appears to be) random places.

Comment: The page number is not part of the thumbnail image, right? Can you show us your code on how you display the thumbnails in the grid shown in your screenshot?

Comment: The screen shot is from Adobe Acrobat. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does this happen with different PDF files too? To me it seems like the PDF files contain their page number as meta data. The meta data is kept on merge and causes re-order when viewing the merged PDF file. But that's just a guess at this point.

Comment: It does happen with different files. I will look into the meta data, good thought.

Comment: I added an example on how to strip the meta data from the merged PDF file. It's worth a try.

Comment: Same results. Frustrating isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no way around this issue, so we are going to use a third party solution to merge our PDF documents.